# Swift - Timer Countdown for gameplay

Tags: ios, swift, timer, countdown

I have looked online at many different 'Timer' tutorials, but they are over-complicated with things like backgrounds e.t.c. What I would like is a timer at the top of the screen that counts down '3, 2, 1, Play'. I will have images instead of text. This timer is activated as soon as a touch - to - begin button is clicked (which I have already made). Any help you can give me to do this in Apple Swift would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: Play around with MZTimerLabel library https://github.com/mineschan/MZTimerLabel, you'll get some idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try the method `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` from `NSTimer`

```
// IBOutlet From Storyboard
@IBOutlet weak var imgView: UIImageView!

var countdown : Int! = 0   // Variable to check the count down seconds

override func viewDidLoad() {
      // Scheduling timer to Call the function **Countdown** with the interval of 1 seconds
      NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("countDown:"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 }

 func countDown(timer: NSTimer) {
    countdown = countdown + 1   
    if (countdown == 1) {       // second 1, show image 3 
        imgView.image = UIImage(named: "three.png")
    }
    else if (countdown == 2) {  // second 2, show image 2
        imgView.image = UIImage(named: "two.png")
    }
    else if (countdown == 3) {  // second 3, show image 1
        imgView.image = UIImage(named: "one.png")
    }
    else if (countdown == 4) {  // second 4, show image 'play'
        imgView.image = UIImage(named: "play.png")            
    }
    else {
    // Invalidate the timer & remove the `time image` and continue with your `gameplay`
        imgView.removeFromSuperview()
        timer.invalidate()
    }
 }
```

Comment: Could you please use comments to explain the different sections of your code. Thank you.

Comment: added with comments, sorry i made some mistakes in `code`, i edited it.

Comment: Instead of using viewDidLoad, would it be possible to connect it to when my tap-to-begin button is hidden?@IBAction func touchToBegin(sender: AnyObject) {
        btnBegin.hidden = true
    }

Comment: yeah you can. paste the `NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` line to your button tap method. and note i edited the code, because if you remove the image on `second 4` user can't see the image `play`.

Comment: I get the error 'imgView' is an unsolved identifier.

Comment: William, clearly in arthankamal's example he assumed you had an image view with an IBOutlet of `imgView` for which you'd be replacing the image once per second. Just replace that `imgView.image = ...` code with whatever UI update is appropriate for your app (e.g. update a label or image view accordingly).

Comment: @Rob Apparently my UIView doesn't have a member named 'image'.

Comment: @Rob It was an UIView, not an UIImageView. Thanks